# How to sign a string in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am designing a system in ruby on rails but I want to know how I can sign a text string using a private key. I am supposed to first encode text using ASCII byte array, then compute byte array hash value using `SHA1` from a byte array, sign byte array of the hashed array using the private key, and then convert the signed array into `base64` . This how am doing it.

```
require 'openssl'
require 'digest/sha1'

    @date = Date.today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    text_to_sign = "#{@order.phone_no}" + "#{@order.name}" + "#{@order.pay_type}" + "#{@order.pay_type}" + "1" + "MABIRA" + "81W30DI846" + "#{@date}" + "PULL" + "1" + "#{@cart.total_price}" + "#{@order.phone_no}" + ""

    password = 'mypassword'
    hashed_text = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(text_to_sign)


    private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read('Mabira.key'), password)
    ciphertext = private_key.private_encrypt(hashed_text)
    signed_text = [ciphertext].pack('m*')#encoding in base64
    puts signed_text
    signed_text
```

Any assistance is welcome.

Comment: what is the actual question?

Comment: Its ok I figured out and I got the answer thank you

Comment: @Becka well, what was the answer?

Comment: This looks abandoned, so, here's a code example I found some in Shopify's docs which helped me achieve this (specific to Rails): https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/webhooks#verify-webhook

And here's this just in case Shopify removes the code example: https://gist.github.com/PureForm/a6370836b30058fb3ff78366c531d485

Comment: If you don't need public key cryptography and HMAC is sufficient, then you can use convenient `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier`.